# Saving data between names in terminal to new files?

Tags: text-processing, files, read

I have the following text file:

```
(Employee Ashley)

insert text here

(Employee Bob)

insert text here

(Employee Joseph)

insert text here
```

I would like to take the text for each "employee" and save it to a new file. I can manually count the number of employees if that's necessary. How can I do this all from terminal?

I was thinking of "awk" then some way of detecting the open parenthesis as that is the only thing that has the text in between and then *in file directory* > *outfile directory*

Could someone help me tie up the loose ends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk ' /^\(Employee/ { FILENAME="";
                      for ( i=2 ; i<=NF; i++)
                         FILENAME=FILENAME $i;
                      FILENAME=substr(FILENAME,1,length(FILENAME)-1) ".txt";
                    }
     !/^\(Employee/ { print >> FILENAME } '
```

This presumes the first line will always be an employee identifier. The `for` loop is to allow for surnames or multiple given names (Betty Lou, Mary Jo, etc.)

Comment: Really efficient implementation.

Answer (score 2):

```
while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line == "(Employee "*")" ]]; then
        t="${line#(Employee }"
        t="${t%)}"
        fn="${t}.txt"
    fi
    echo "$line" >>$fn
done <original_file.txt
```

This will put the text in `Ashley.txt`, `Bob.txt`, `Joseph.txt`, &c.

Comment: I like the approach, though I suspect they just want all the names in a single file, which your answer can be easily adapted to do

Comment: I really like this approach, I actually have this in mind for something else. Thank you!